# Automation framework to automate an scenarios from a web application to mobile application

Tags: java, android, selenium, testng, appium

I would like to know a working framework or a methodology to automate a script which has to run on both web and mobile for a single scenario.

Assume the scenario is that you have booked a cargo to deliver from Goa to Delhi using a front office web application and you have received a shipment number.Now the delivery team has a mobile application using which they keep updating the status of the shipment as – Started from Source station, On Route, Delivered in Destination.

As the delivery team updates the status on the mobile app, this status should reflect in the web application when you track the shipment number as a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked with a similar issue in the past, where a test case requires testing on both mobile and web browser platforms.

You need to implement two different `CreateDriver` methods within a `DriverManager` class - one for Appium driver (for mobile), and one for Selenium WebDriver (for web browser). Your test case will need to specify when to 'switch' from web to mobile, or mobile to web. You also need to include a method to stop the Appium server, to use when switching from mobile to web. Here's a small, generic example of how this would work:

```
public class DriverFactory
{

    private static AppiumLocalService _appiumLocalService;

    // use Current instance to act as static DriverFactory class instance
    private static DriverFactory _current;
    public static DriverFactory Current => _current ?? (_current = new DriverFactory());

    public AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement> CreateAndroidDriver()
    {
        // start Appium server
        var builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        _appiumLocalService = builder.UsingAnyFreePort().Build();
        _appiumLocalService.Start();

        // set desired capabilities or appium options here
        var options = new AppiumOptions {PlatformName = "Android"};

        // start AndroidDriver session
        var driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(_appiumLocalService.ServiceUrl, options);

        return driver;
    }

    public void StopAppiumService()
    {
        // stop appium server
        _appiumLocalService.Dispose();

    }

    public IWebDriver CreateSeleniumDriver()
    {
        // create browser-specific webdriver here
        // return webdriver
    }
}
```

Then, you can implement a `BaseTestFixture` that handles starting and stopping each Driver for you. This class also contains instances of both Selenium WebDriver, and Appium driver. Every test class you write should inherit from this fixture, to inherit both driver instances.

```
public class BaseTestFixture
{
    public static AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement> AppiumDriver { get;set; }
    public static IWebDriver SeleniumDriver { get set; }

    public void SetAppiumDriver()
    {
        AppiumDriver = DriverFactory.Current.CreateAndroidDriver();
    }

    public void TearDownAppiumDriver()
    {
        AppiumDriver.Close();
        AppiumDriver.Quit();
        DriverFactory.Current.StopAppiumService();
    }

    public void SetSeleniumDriver()
    {
        SeleniumDriver = DriverFactory.Current.CreateSeleniumDriver();
    }

    public void TearDownSeleniumDriver()
    {
        SeleniumDriver.Close();
        SeleniumDriver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Lastly -- here is how `BaseTestFixture` can get used in a Test class:

```
using MyProject.BaseTestFixture;

[TestFixture]
public class MyTestClass : BaseTestFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldStartBothDrivers()
    {
        // set Appium driver -- we are testing with mobile
        SetAppiumDriver();

        // perform testing with Appium driver
        AppiumDriver.FindElement(.....);

        // finished mobile testing -- move to web browser
        TearDownAppiumDriver();

        // set Selenium driver -- web browser testing
        SetSeleniumDriver();

        // perform testing with Selenium driver
        SeleniumDriver.FindElement(....);

        // finished web browser testing -- close selenium driver
        TearDownSeleniumDriver();
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, this is a very generic example and will require customization on your end to meet your specific needs. This is just sample architecture for how both drivers could be handled. Hope this helps.